# Desmarcar CheckBox cuando recargas la pàgina

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

Tengo la duda de como poder desmarcar un checkbox automáticamente cuando recargas la página de nuevo en JavaScript o HTML.

Muchas gracias ^^

Comment: Hola Jordi. ¿Qué has intentado o investigado?  Recuerda que aqui ayudamos con problemas concretos no con tareas. Te sugiero que guardes en cookies o en `localStorage` el valor de un checkbox y al cargar una pagina comprobar si el estado ha cambiado y hacer lo propio. Un saludo

Comment: he probado un ejemplo en HTML y se supone que si en el input no esta el atributo "checked", al recargar la pagina se auto desmarca solo el recuadro. Espero que te sirva de ayuda ^^

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres que despues de recargar la pagina por un POST fallido o por mala validacion, el checkbox este desmarcado, puedes utilizar el atributo `autocomplete`.

```
 <input type="checkbox" value="checkbox" autocomplete="off">
```

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo muy bien tu pregunta pero si lo que quieres es que el checkbox se muestre desmarcado puedes quitar el tag checked del input:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="myvalue" id="mycheckbox">
```

Si lo que quieres es cambiar el valor por javascript debes hacer:

```
document.getElementById('mycheckbox').checked=false;
```

espero te sirva.

Comment: Hola jQuero, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio.  Gracias por aportar pero es mejor esperar a que el autor aclare la pregunta. podria resolverse como dice a menos que ese checkbox en particular no deba ser siempre inicializado a false...  Un saludo.